# Python not overlapping letters

Tags: python, overlapping

Here is my code:

```
    a = raw_input("Haystack ")
    b = raw_input("Needle ")

    common = {}
    if len(a)<len(b):
    for letter in a:
        if letter in b:
            common[letter]= 1

    else:
      for letter in b:
         if letter in a:
            common[letter]= 1
    print (len(common))
```

I made a code about needle in haystack. But I can't seem to figure out how to add to the code that it has to read non-overlapping letters. For example. If user types after haystack "qqwwee" and after the needle "qw" then it has to output 1 not 2, because there is only one "qw" in haystack.

Comment: Hey ? Can you check your indentation ?

Comment: what is input? and what should be output?

Comment: Input is user input "a and b" and output should be the times needle appears in haystack

Comment: I'm not supposed to use any text comparing methods like "count" or "findall". That's why I had to make my own algorithm for this code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you don't have to iterate through all the elements of b and a because you are searching for the whole word, instead you can use regular expressions.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

a = raw_input("Haystack ")
b = raw_input("Needle ")

reg = re.compile(b)
c = Counter(word.group() for word in reg.finditer(a))
print(c)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you add the line where it doesn't count overlapping letters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` method after getting input's from user

```
In [13]: a='qqwwee'

In [14]: 'qw' in a
Out[14]: True

In [15]: 'qwe' in a
Out[15]: False

In [16]: a='qqwweqwe'

In [17]: 'qw' in a
Out[17]: True

In [18]: a.count('qw')
Out[18]: 2

In [19]: a='qqwqqweqwe'

In [20]: a.count('qw')
Out[20]: 3
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but it would profit from better formatting and explanation instead of just dumping an IPython log.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that you want. It will check the count of string a into string b or vice versa based on their length.

```
a = raw_input("Haystack ")
b = raw_input("Needle ")

if len(a)<len(b):
    print str(b.count(a))
else:
    print str(a.count(b))
```